# Scrolling down on a Mobile Phone

Tags: mobile

```
 http://54.200.76.33:8080/
```

I've got this working on desktop browsers.If you scroll down, you'll see a search bar shows up at the bottom of the screen and becomes fixed to the bottom.

If you look at this on a mobile phone, when you scroll down, the bar doesn't immediately stick to the bottom. It'll wait until the user stops scrolling, and then it becomes fixed to the bottom.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different mobile browsers have all kinds of issues with firing scroll events.  Seems like you're using a scroll listener to update the CSS for pinning the scrollbar to the bottom.  It's a generally good approach, so I wouldn't change it.

If you like, you can use a tool like Modernizr to treat the mobile platform differently.  Other than that, the state of technology today is that you kind of have to deal with quirks like this on mobile.

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Sure thing. If you found it useful, you can click to mark my answer as correct. That way future viewers who come across this question will know that the answer was useful